# Select rows based on value which exists in other table as text

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to simplify as much as I could. Given two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE house ( `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL, `nb` INTEGER  NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE room  ( `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL, `body` TEXT );
```

containing data like so:

```
INSERT INTO house VALUES (1, 111);
INSERT INTO house VALUES (2, 222);
INSERT INTO house VALUES (3, 333);
INSERT INTO house VALUES (4, 444);

INSERT INTO room VALUES (1, 'lorem ipsum House NR: 111 dolor sit ames');
INSERT INTO room VALUES (2, 'lorem m House NR: 777 dolor sit ames');
INSERT INTO room VALUES (3, 'lopsu House NR: 32154 dolor sit ames');
INSERT INTO room VALUES (4, 'ipsa House NR: 222 dolor sit ames');
INSERT INTO room VALUES (5, 'ipsa House NR: 222222 dolor sit ames');
```

**What I need** is to get all data from `house` and `room` based on the **`house nb`** which also exists in **`room body`** as string just after `House NR: [NR]` all the rest of string/text in `house body` before `House NR:` and after the `[NR]` can vary.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE body LIKE '%House NR: 111%';
```

works fine. Then I tried to make `LIKE '%House NR: 111%'` dynamic with the `house nb` like:

```
SELECT *, concat('\'%House NR:', nb, '%\'') as value FROM house;
```

value correct. But how to get all values together? I've tried:

```
SELECT id, nb
FROM house h,
    (
        SELECT 
            body
        FROM room
    ) AS r
WHERE  r.body LIKE concat('\'%House NR:', h.nb, '%\'')
```

but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**Expected result is two rows**

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| house.id | house.nb | room.id | room.body                                  |
+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| 1        | 111      | 1       | 'lorem ipsum House NR: 111 dolor sit ames' |
+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| 2        | 222      | 4       | 'ipsa House NR: 222 dolor sit ames'        |
+----------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle to play with here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8edf8f/3/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I notice is that you are not accounting for the space between `House NR:` and the number. Assuming there is always exactly one space after the `House NR:` then you can join the two tables like this:

```
SELECT house.*, room.*
from house 
inner join room on room.body like concat('%House NR: ', house.nb, ' %');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to achieve this. I am assuming dataset is not huge. Example below

```
SELECT * FROM room 
WHERE body REGEXP 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('House NR: ', nb SEPARATOR '|') as value FROM house);
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/114cd/23/0)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to SQL Server Databases:**
Based on your query, you can just explicit concatenate without using the concat fuction:

```
SELECT h.id, h.nb, r.id, r.body
FROM house h,
    (
        SELECT id,
            body
        FROM room
    ) AS r
WHERE  r.body LIKE '%House NR: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), h.nb) +  '%'
```

Comment: This gives me `You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Comment: Ok, so I suppose you are using MySQL. This solutions applies to SQL Server.

Comment: open link from the question (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8edf8f/3/0), copy paste your query, click Run SQL, see Error